# PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128 ciphers but doesn't decipher

Tags: java, encryption

I'm able to cipher using PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128 , but when i try to decipher it doesnt do anything, my encrypt code is:

```
                PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passwordServer.toCharArray());
            SecretKeyFactory kf;

                kf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128");

                secretKey = kf.generateSecret(keySpec); 
                byte[] ivBytes = {0x11,0x12,0x13,0x14,0x15,0x16,0x17,0x18,
                        0x19,0x1A,0x1B,0x1C,0x1D,0x1E,0x1F,0x20};
                IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

                PBEParameterSpec spec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, 20, ivSpec);

                c = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128");
                c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, spec);
                params = c.getParameters();
```

and my decrypt code is the following:

```
                Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128");
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, params);

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("repositorios/login.cif");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("repositorios/login2.txt");
            CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, c);

            byte[] b = new byte[16]; 
            int i = fis.read(b);
            while (i != -1) {
                cos.write(b, 0, i);
                i = fis.read(b);
            }
            cos.close();
            fis.close();
```

After i run the code, the file "login2.txt" is empty.
Am I doing something wrong while using this algorithm?
Thank you!

EDIT:
1. where i store the salt:

```
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter
                        (new FileWriter("repositorios/salt.txt",true));
                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader
                        (new FileReader("repositorios/salt.txt"));
                byte[]salt;
                String l = in.readLine();
                if(l != null){
                    salt = l.getBytes();
                } else {
                    salt = new byte[16];
                    RANDOM.nextBytes(salt);
                    out.write(new String (salt, "UTF-8"));
                }
```

2. my chiper code:

   ```
               FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("repositorios/login.cif");
           CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, c);

           out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("repositorios/login.txt",true));


           String aEncriptar = user + ":" + passwd +"\n";
           byte[] b= aEncriptar.getBytes();
           cos.write(b, 0, b.length);
           cos.close();
   ```

Comment: show your cipher code as well please. how long is the encrypted file for which input length. What crypto provider do you use? How do you store the salt?

Comment: BTW: I think using CipherInputStream for decryption looks nicer, it operates on the file which is actually ciphered.

Comment: I added the code in the question above

Comment: Hm, that salt handling does not look right, you can't use string functions on random bytes (at least not with readline and unspecific encoding). You should also specify an encoding in `aEncryptar.getBytes(StandardCharSet.UTF8);` (but that's not the issue). I am not sure about the getParameter() part, would need to test that, I would have reconstructed the specs.